# Xamarin Form System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer throws System.TypeInitializationException on iOS only

Tags: xamarin, system.text.json

The following code throws an exception ONLY on iOS - on Android it works as expected:

```
var content = new StringContent(
                            JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { UserName = userName, Password = password }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

I saw the article at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/302548/jsonserializer-throws-exception-in-xamarinios.html but that solution did not solve my issue.

Any ideas? Or do I go back to Newtonsoft?

Comment: generally Newtonsoft is much preferred over JsonSerializer.

Comment: If you're on .net core 3 then you could try to explicetly reference the latest System.Text.Json (5.0.2 @ Apr 2021).

Comment: Newtonsoft is preferred. What exception you are getting? Is that same exception which was in your reference link? Add try catch if you are not able capture exception exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is that you have to be using .net framework 2.1 (not 2.0 as the wizard apparently set). Then, System.Text.JsonSerializer works as expected on both iOS and Android.